# Are the following properties equivalent?

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

I am interested in the following question:
Are pseudofiniteness and homogeneity(of models) equivalent?

Comment: Way too many questions in one post.  Needs more focus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of these equivalences hold.

*Example A:* The structure $(\mathbb{Q},<)$ is homogeneous, has countably categorical theory, and is Fraïssé limit of the class of all finite linear orders. But it is not pseudofinite.

*Example B:* Let $(L,<)$ be any infinite ultraproduct of finite linear orders. Then $L$ is pseudofinite. But it is not homogeneous, it does not have countably categorical theory, and it is not a Fraïssé limit.

Examples A and B show that equivalences 1, 2, and 4 fail, and in fact there is no implication in either direction between pseudofiniteness and these properties.

For 3, Ax famously axiomatized psuedofinite fields: they are the quasi-finite psuedo-algebraically closed (PAC) fields. So for fields, psuedofinite implies PAC, but PAC does not imply psuedofinite. You ask "why do pseudo-finite fields require quasi-finiteness in addition to being pseudo-algebraically closed?" Well, because there are PAC fields which are not quasi-finite! I'm not sure what other kind of answer you could be looking for...

For 5, the theory of pseudofinite fields is not quasi-finitely axiomatizable. Conversely, the theory of dense linear orders without endpoints is finitely axiomatizable but not pseudofinite.

Finally, you write "there is an assumption that a countably categorical structure is pseudofinite if and only if it is smoothly approximable." This is false. The random graph is countably categorical and pseudofinite but not smoothly approximable.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I apologize for the bad (english) grammar.
Actually, I wanted to clarify when these (homogeneous, omega-categorical) structures are pseudofinite. That is, I would like to find a more general criterion. I know that you studied just pseudo-finite countably categorical structures. The question arose about when a countably categorical structure is pseudofinite, although they lie on different parts (syntax and semantics).

Comment: I read, https://www3.nd.edu/~apillay/notes_greg-final.pdf, turns out I missed the exercise about the random graph is not smoothly approximable. It turned out that any smoothly approximable structure is pseudofinite, but not vice versa. OK. In graphs, let pseudofiniteness not imply smooth approximability. We will look for structures (fields, groups, rings) in which they coincide.

Comment: And about pseudo-algebraically closed fields. It became clearer to me after reading Yu. L. Ershov, “Regularly closed fields”, Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR, 251:4 (1980), 783–785, Yu. L. Ershov, “Fields with a solvable theory”, Dokl. Akad. Nauk SSSR, 174:1 (1967), 19–20

Thanks again for the detailed answer!